# can't make junction and group by

Tags: mysql, group-by, junction

I have two tables :

```
GererLocationAppart(IdAppartL, MatriculeEmploye)
Employe(MatriculeEmploye, PrenomEmploye, NomEmploye, NumeroTelephoneEmploye)
```

I would like to get a table wich contains "PrenomEmploye", "NomEmploye" and a column "Id AppartL". This last column should have the number of lines that every "MatriculeEmploye" are referring to.
I know that i should do a mixture between

```
Select Distinct PrenomEmploye, NomEmploye, IdAppartL
From Employe E1, GererLocationAppart G1
Where E1.MatriculeEmploye=G1.MatriculeEmploye;
```

And

```
SELECT MatriculeEmploye, COUNT(IdAppartL)
FROM GererLocationAppart
GROUP BY MatriculeEmploye;
```

But i don't know how..
I try :

```
Select Distinct PrenomEmploye, NomEmploye
From Employe
Where MatriculeEmploye in
(SELECT MatriculeEmploye, COUNT(IdAppartL)
FROM GererLocationAppart
GROUP BY MatriculeEmploye);
```

But I get :

```
ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subquery after `IN` must return only 1 column.  You are returning `MatriculeEmploye, COUNT(IdAppartL)` so 2 columns.  Your query should be something like:

```
Select e.PrenomEmploye, e.NomEmploye, COUNT(g.IdAppartL)
From Employe e 
  INNER JOIN GererLocationAppart g ON g.MatriculeEmploye=e.MatriculeEmploye
GROUP BY 1,2;
```

Note that that this query will merge employees that have the same (Prenom, Nom) couple, so you may also want to add e.MatriculeEmploye to the SELECT and GROUP BY clause (`GROUP BY 1,2,3` if you change your select to `SELECT e.MatriculeEmploye, e.Prenom, ...`).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
 E1.PrenomEmploye
,E1.NomEmploye
,E1.IdAppartL
,COUNT(G1.IdAppartL) as CountMatriculeEmploye
From Employe E1
JOIN GererLocationAppart G1 ON E1.MatriculeEmploye=G1.MatriculeEmploye
GROUP BY E1.MatriculeEmploye;
```